# SQL Server stored procedure performance issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have function they call lot of stored procedures on our project.

Sometimes some  stored procedures work very slowly when we alter stored procedure, problems fixed but after 10 days problems occurs again. We use reindexing, optimizing query etc...

But we did not find any stable solution.

Does anyone have idea about this type of problem

thanks...

Comment: I think we'd need more concrete information - with the information you've given us, your guess is about as good as ours.

Comment: it'd be easier if you provided an example of what your sp looks like

Comment: Compare the query plan of the stored procedure when it's ok and when it running very slowly. It's likely that SQL Server is changing the query plan over time and updating statistics will help but you may also be able to tweak the stored procedure for better performance with the information you get from comparing the query plans.

Answer (score 4):

If the stored procedures randomly run slowly and running an `alter` on them sorts it out then this sounds like a parameter sniffing issue.

Running an `ALTER` will cause the cached plan to be dropped for that procedure and it will be recompiled on the next execution. [A good article on the area is here](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: sp_recompile should help.
A simple explanation on MSDN of why one must sometimes recompile sp :
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your statistics.

```
EXEC sp_updatestats
```